# Q: I can't start Database connection in Eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse, tomcat, derby

I try about half a day to start database server in Eclipse without effect...

I've the newest Eclipse MARS. I opened the view of `Data Source Explorer` and right-click on the `Database Connections`, choose `New > Derby` and `Define new driver` of `Derby Client JDBC Driver 10.2` and select `JAR List > ADD JAR/Zip`, I downloaded the driver to derby `version 10.2.2.0`.

I set...

`Database: sample
Host: localhost
Port number: 1527
User name: sa
Password: sa`

..and try to run the new created server and then ERROR pop-up with information

```
Could not connect to New Derby.
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to New Derby. (Error: java.net.ConnectException: Error when connect with server localhost at port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.)
```

Anyone have problem with that ? I try the same with other type of databse (I try MySQL, downloded too the newest drivers and I have the same error).

Comment: Do you have a derby database running on your machine?

Comment: what platform are you on? If on linux, you can check if mysql is running using ```/etc/init.d mysqld status```

Comment: I can't run the derby database... I have Tomcat 7.0 and I'm on Windows 64-bit and want create Derby database, I try with several tutorials but always the same error like I wrote up.

Comment: What are you expecting to connect to, if you have no Derby / MySQL databse running at localhost?

Comment: I try configure and run the Derby server, downloaded and put the `derbyclient.jar` in Tomcat/lib but doesn't works.What I should do ? Can You write it at 1...2..3.. steps ? Maybe I did something wrong

Comment: All the steps you described are to set up a *connection to a server from the client*, not setting up a server. See, it says derbyclient.jar - it means it's the client, the driver for the connection.

Comment: What I should do to run this server and set up a connection to this server from client ?

Comment: Or whether it has something to do with Tomcat ? Becafuse I used Tomcat 7.0 in my project

Comment: Perhaps you should follow the [Derby Quick Start page](https://db.apache.org/derby/quick_start.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the official instructions to install and run the database server!

[Apache Derby Server Tutorial](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/index.html)

When your server is running, you can setup the connection.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. I'll answer You for 8 hours how situation looks, because I must go sleep now

Comment: I did everything what was in this Tutorial which You told and i meet the same problem like in Eclipse. It means, when I was on Step 4 - `Test network server connection with ij` and write on my Windows CMD line when I was in `ij>` `connect 'jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;create=true';` error shows `No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;create=true` and my head goes down... I did EVERYTHING correct but the error totally confounds me... I try second in command line, like `connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDbTest;create=true';` and i catched the same error when do connection in Eclipse..HELP!

Comment: Also when I try do Import project in Eclipse in directory `"D:\Derby\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\demo\programs\simple"` the Eclipse told me that `No projects are found to import`...

Comment: And when i try to start server in command line `java -jar derbyrun.jar server start` nothing gonna happen, althouh it should return information about IP and port on which it should start....

Comment: Does not look like you did everything according to the tutorial if you still get errors.. As your last comment says, something has to happen when starting the server!! Only if it this command successfully runs you can connect to the database.

Comment: You don't understand, NOTHING happens, no information about start server